# Как по протоколу IMAP получить письма из папки SPAM?

Tags: php, imap

Имею дело с Яндексом. Получаю доступ к чтению писем по IMAP потоку без проблем. Но меня интересуют письма из папки "Спам", которых нет в выдачи. Что посоветуете? Не хотелось бы перемещать письма из этой папки, но нужно их обработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$folder = imap_utf8_to_mutf7('Спам');
$mailbox = imap_open('{imap.yandex.ru:993/ssl}' . $folder, 'user', 'pass');
$count = imap_num_msg($mailbox);

echo 'Количество писем в ящике: '. $count . "\n";

imap_close($mailbox);
```